# gdb pretty printing inconsistency

Tags: python, c++, gdb, pretty-print

I'm trying to figure out an inconsistency in the gdb pretty printing.
Consider the following short program:

```
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int i=5;
  int* p=&i;
  std::map<int,int*> m;
  m[3]=p;
  return 0;
}
```

If I place a breakpoint on the `return 0;` line, and print the pointer, I get:

```
(gdb) print p
$1 = (int *) 0xbffff12c
```

If I print the contents of the map, I get:

```
(gdb) print m
$2 = std::map with 1 elements = {[3] = 0xbffff12c}
```

Notice that the pointer type information is now stripped.  Obviously with a simple map type that's not a real problem, but in large programs with nested data structures, not having this information is a problem.

The reason I find this strange, is that I would assume that nested objects are printed using their respective pretty printer, which should have produced the type information just like when I printed the pointer directly.

I tried looking at the STL pretty printing python code, but can't figure out how to fix this issue.  I can see the std::map printer iterator returns objects as they're queried from the RB tree, but there's no formatting done there.

I would appreciate any help in the form of what change is needed in the python printer code, location in the code of where the change is likely to be done, or any other clue.

### EDIT:

I investigated the gdb code and it seems there are two separate functions that print native C type variables:

1. `c_value_print()`  @ `c-valprint.c:459`  which is called for the simple pointer print, and prints the type
2. `c_val_print()`    @ `c-valprint.c:134`  which is called from the children printing of the pretty printer.  This one doesn't print pointer types

Since there is duplicate code there, this looks like patch work that probably accumulated in this code base.

This is very disappointing.  I would suggest a change, but this tool is used in so many environments, I wouldn't have any way of testing a change.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What, or at least where should a change be done to the printer code to fix this.   Or any other clue to help with this issue.

Comment: You should include the real question in yor post then! Edit it.

Comment: It's (arguably) a bug in gdb.  You'll have to dig in to the C code to find out where the type isn't printed.  Alternatively maybe there's some way to do it from the pretty-printer itself (stringizing the value there might work) -- but this isn't as good as a fix in the core.